# KafkaStreams KTable Aggregate Incorrect Results

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have noticed an issue whereby the Kafka **at-least-once** messaging guarantee is causing incorrect output for the Kafka Streams `KTable.aggregate()` in the case of a client disconnection/unstable cluster.

I have a topology like this:

`Input: Client Sales -> Repartition: By Product -> Aggregate: Sum of Sales By Product`

The aggregator is pretty simple:

`adder: (total, sale) -> total + sale`

`subtractor: (total, sale ) -> total - sale`

Now I have found that on occasion usually after a rebalance/broker disconnection that the total can end up incorrect and even negative!

It appears that on consumer reconnection that messages are reprocessed from the last committed offset (not the same as last processed offset) and these will be reapplied to the aggregate state. e.g. subtractor called again when total has already been subtracted.

What is the correct pattern to handle these issues in the Kafka Streams aggregate? (given the absence of EOS - exactly-once-semantics)

1. Thinking I can store all of the sales ids inside the aggregate and
   check these, but then the aggregate state becomes large.
2. Alternatively should I store the last processed (added/subtracted)
   offset inside the aggregate and use these to dedupe?
3. Or is there something I am doing wrong with Kafka Steams to get into
   this situation in the first place as the DSL docs do not warn about
   it. Or a Kafka Streams bug?

Comment: It seems like you are asking "how can I get exactly once semantics without enabling exactly once semantics". Why are you excluding enabling EOS upfront?